# Returning to coffee script calling a controller method, without rendering a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

```
Rails 3.2.18
Ruby 2.1.5
Ubuntu 14.04
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
post '/tracker' => 'loggers#create'
```

In my loggers_controller.rb, I have:

```
class LoggersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    logger.info(params[:data])
  end
end
```

In the coffee script file I am calling this from, I have:

```
$.post '/tracker', { data: "some text"}
```

When the code runs, I am getting an error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template loggers/create
```

I understand why I am getting the message, but what do I need to do to make sure that control is returned to the coffee scriptthat called the controller method, so the next statement in the coffee script is executed?

What I am looking for essentially is a way to log something in the log file from the coffee script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the controller action will have to return a status for your request, even if you do not want any content. The easiest way to do that is to use `head :no_content` in your action, right after the `logger.info` call. This will return a success status (204), but won't try to render any template. You could also use `head :ok`, but no_content is clearer as you are actually not sending back any content. So:

```
def create
  logger.info(params[:data])
  head :no_content
end
```

Please also note that technically your javascript never loses control, as the request is asynchronous and the script will immediately continue its execution unless you specify a callback.

Comment: This works. I do have another side effect though. The coffee script is populating a dropdown list and now when I click on the down arrow, the list shows for a split second and then disappears without allowing to make a selection.

Comment: Can you post the coffeescript code which does that?

Comment: Mistake on my part. I put the call to the controller outside any of the functions inside the class, making it get stuck in a loop. I saw that when I went into firefly and saw that it was looping

Comment: It turns out that was not the issue. The file is too long, I will send it to you. I am just getting started with coffee script as most of the stuff I've written to date is backend.

Comment: I edited the question to add the entire coffee script

Comment: I think you should post this as a separate question, the problem is not related to the initial one. Also, you should give some indication of where you think the issue is in the coffeescript, as there is quite a bit of code. Most likely an event is triggered when the user first clicks on the dropdown, which changes the `select` itself, while you'd want to trigger such event only once a selection is made.